# Configurable product set variant per store view

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, configurable-product, product-attribute, inventory

I have cloths website, with multi store view for french, germany etc. For a configurable product with attributes like say color, size say:

Size: M, L, XL
Color: red, green, yellow, black

I have created that configurable product and it works absolutely fine. Now the requirement is say for france, the shirt is available in color green and black with size L only. So when a visitor selects france, it will only show these options only to select and not other options, and same for other store.
Is there is any way or any other module/extension to manage it?

Comment: You can use the scope view for attributes but I don't think that works very well for your case. For example if you disable size XL for a store view it will be disabled for all products in that store view.

Comment: Yup, already did that but not the flung which i'm looking for

Comment: However one workaround that comes to my mind is that you set a default value for your custom attributes and then set that for the products that you want them not to have that attribute. Then hide that attribute in a phtml file. Check this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/How-to-remove-empty-attributes-N-A-in-Magento-2/td-p/69329 it is for normal attributes but I guess you can get an idea for custom attributes also.

Comment: Thanks, its not good for me, since the need is that client can manage the attributes which they wants to show on which store, also its not a good practice to hide and also the attributes are not fixed because they have other kind of config products as well, which they needs to manage per store view.

Comment: Maybe you could look for an extension that allows you to manage stock on a per-store-view level. You could then take products that are not available in a specific store view offline by simply setting it to "out of stock"